# External Jar Files issue Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, classpath, buildpath

My project is using some jars which are dependent on the external jar `httpclient-4.2.3.`
In eclipse my project is running smoothly.
But when I am creating a Jar of my project it is showing error.
I found the error that it is picking `httpclient` from mahout jars which is an `older version`.
I know we can control `classpath ordering` of `external jars` through `order and export` in `eclipse` but it is not working properly.
Can someone tell me how I can force eclipse to prioritize some jars over another when I am creating jar of my projectc.

Comment: There are so many ways to create a distributable JAR file from Eclipse. So, please tell us how you create the distribution and what it contains (and - of course - how you run your program outside of Eclipse).

Comment: I created a runnable jar and package the required libraries into generated jar

Comment: Hmmm ... I do not really understand. How do you manage the external libraries? Are they put into a lib folder inside the project folder? Are you using Eclipse's user libraries? What is your build path? How could you have the httpclient-library two times?